# Exporting to MS Word in Cocoa?

Tags: cocoa, ms-word, ms-office, export-to-word

Writing an application in Cocoa that will take input from the user, format it appropriately, and then export it to MS Word.  Are there any references or built-in libraries available regarding how to go about this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can use `-docFormatFromRange:documentAttributes:` from `NSAttributedString` to do this. See Apple's documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring/1528592-docformat/).

Answer (score 0):

It somewhat depends on what you are trying to achieve, but you can use Applescript to control MS Word such as creating new documents, inserting text into a document etc.